# How to convert .cer file to .pem in the browser

Tags: javascript, x509

The cer file I'm reading in from a file input, I can then use the fileReader to get the contents. I was expecting the file to have start and end comments but it doesn't.

How can I convert the cer to pem in the browser, without uploading the file to a server?

What I really want is something like

```
openssl x509 -in cert.cer -out cert.pem
```

but in the browser

I've also tried a few x509 packages from npm, like...

```
import * as x509 from '@peculiar/x509';
...
  const uploadCsr = async (fileArr: File[]): Promise<void> => {
    const file = fileArr[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e: any): void => {
      const cert = new x509.X509Certificate(e.target.result);
      console.log('cert', cert); 
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  };
```

but the error I get is

```
TypeError: Unsupported format of 'raw' argument. Must be one of DER, PEM, HEX, Base64, or Base4Url
```

Comment: It seems that Chilkat has a library for it: https://www.example-code.com/nodejs/cert_convert_to_pem.asp

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the `readAsArrayBuffer` with `@peculiar/x509` and `.toString('pem');`

```
import * as x509 from '@peculiar/x509';
...

  const checkCsr = async (fileArr: File[]): Promise<void> => {
    setServerError('');
    const file = fileArr[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = async (e: any): Promise<void> => {
      const cert = new x509.X509Certificate(e.target.result);
      const expires = Date.parse(`${cert.notAfter}`) / 1000;
      const now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
      if (now > expires) setServerError('Certificate has expired');
      const issuerArr = cert.issuer.split('=');
      if (!issuerArr[3].includes('Apple Inc'))
        setServerError('Certificate not issued by Apple Inc');
      const pem = cert.toString('pem');
      if (!serverError) setCertificatePem(pem);
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  };
```